# Does AMP execute PHP? Or does it just store the HTML output?

Tags: php, amp-html

As I understand it, the AMP cache retains query parameters and PHP can reference them. Eg. `google.com/amp/example.com?test=1` and `echo $_GET['test']` will output 1

My question is, does AMP actually execute the PHP at load time? Or has it stored a copy of the HTML output relative to that URL?

Specifically, would `echo date('U')` output a different number on every view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMP Cache will cache your page for a certain amount of time using a [stale-while-revalidate strategy](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#google-amp-cache-updates) (depending on the max-age header you serve your page with). It does not execute PHP.

> Specifically, would echo date('U') output a different number on every view?

Not by every view, but every time it requests a new version of your page.